# Neo4j Hadoop Integration

Tags: hadoop, neo4j, hive

I am completely new to neo4j. I have some data in hive like

## emp_id  mngr_id

12163   2232
2232    1226
4456    1178
1226    1134
1865    1099
1134    1058
1058    null
1099    null

i want to find hierarchy from this table such as for emp_id 12163, finding the highest hierarchy in manger table is 1058. How can this be implemented in neo4j

Answer (score 0):

You can import these as CSV files into Neo4j and then run an algorithm like, this:

I assume it is "child parent"

Take a random node and find the root.

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n
LIMIT 1
MATCH (n)-[:PARENT*]->(root)
WHERE NOT (root)-[:PARENT]->()
RETURN root
```

Or in Java

```
Node n = db.getNodeById(0);
while (n.hasRelationship(RelTypes.PARENT, Direction.OUTGOING)) {
    n = n.getSingleRelationship(RelTypes.PARENT, Direction.OUTGOING).getEndNode();
}
```

Comment: ok I executed the below command  
    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "/home/pooja/data.csv" AS csvLine
    CREATE (p:people { emp_id: toInt(csvLine.emp_id), mngr_id: toInt(csvLine.mngr_id) })
    Can u please tell me what is n, Parent and root in your program